# Jbehave : GivenStories in the end of execution

Tags: jbehave

I'm using a GivenStories for executing Login scenario which is located in different story.
I was wondering if there is a way to use something similar in order to execute a logout story which is also located in different story than one I actually executing.

I know that I can do some tricks with @before/after annotations , but the question is if I can execute a "post" story

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer I got from the jbehave dev channel.

> Hi,
>
> there is no such mechanism, but you could:
>
> use the Lifecycle to execute steps (not stories) after the execution
>   of a scenario (executed after each scenario) have a final scenario
>   which invokes the given stories

Answer (score 1):

Based on the jBehave [annotation documentation](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/annotations.html) a post story step can be implemented by annotating a step class method with `@AfterStory` (or `@AfterStories` if you want to execute only after all stories complete). The `@AfterStory` method will execute regardless of whether your executing story contains a step from the related step class (i.e. is guaranteed to execute after every story - see below for restricting to given stories).

> The @BeforeStory and @AfterStory annotations allow the corresponding
>   methods to be executed before and after each story, either a
>   GivenStory or not:
>
> ```java
> @AfterStory // equivalent to @AfterStory(uponGivenStory=false)
> public void afterStory() {
>     // ...
> }
>
> @AfterStory(uponGivenStory=true)
> public void afterGivenStory() {
>     // ...
> }
> ```